# Why doesn't Spring Data allow page size zero?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-data

I have the following scenario. There is a typical list view with endless scroll and a Spring MVC backend with controllers. The method which returns the list items has a parameter of type *Pageable* to pass in the current page and the page size. This parameter is delegated to a repository method defined by a corresponding *PagingAndSortingRepository* in order to retrieve the results from database. This will result in two database queries: One count query and one query to fetch the results from the given page.

This works excellent, however, I have another view which defines a button to navigate to the described list view. This button shows a badge with the total elements in that list as a kind of preview. In order to calculate the total elements I am using the same controller and repository method as for the list itself, although I only need the count.

My first attempt to implement this was to set page size and page both to zero in order to count the results without fetching any elements and then access the *totalElements* attribute of the returned page. However, Spring does not allow page size == 0 and will set a default value (e.g. 10) in that case.

Would't it make sense to implement the size == 0 case as a single count query to support the given scenario? I have this use case in several parts of my application and without this feature I would have to write additional, in my opinion, unnecessary count methods. Or is there another way to accomplish what I've described using Spring Data?

Comment: This would mean that there would be some implicit behavior based on some setting of a property which wasn't intended for that. Generally you want those things to be explicit and not be toggled on the value of a property which is actually to be used for something else. I would probably reuse the same method, set max page size to 1 (instead of zero). That way you still have the count and a single element. Else create a `count` method to do the stuff and make it explicit.

Comment: Thx for your response. I understand your point. The page size 1 is how I am currently using it. However, this still requires an unnecessary query. My personal opinion is setting page size to 0 is actually not a use for something else or misuse. If I expect 0 results, I'll just set page size to 0. The main point is that you will often have such a scenario where you first have a preview of the total count and then with another click you will get the respective content. When writing a separate count query I'll also have to deal with an additional controller method and this for numerous views.

Answer (score 0):

you can use just [count](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.core-concepts) no need to go through `Pageable`

`Long count();`

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am using a complex query with a complex _where clause_ and I want to reuse this method for the count. Otherwise I had to rewrite this method and provide an extra count query. It would be more convenient to use the count from the returned _Page_ object.